# How to get object type of pointer to non-static data member at compile time?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits, member-pointers

Suppose we have a simple data class like this:

```
struct DataObj
{ 
  char member[32];
}
```

And the type of pointer to the member in the data object:

```
typedef decltype(&DataObj::member) memberObjPtr;
```

How can I deduce the type of the member variable the pointer points to?
Specifically, how do I get:

```
typedef myExpression<memberObjPtr>::type myType;
std::is_same<char[32],myType>::value == true
```

What I tried so far:

```
std::remove_pointer
std::remove_reference
std::decay
```

Without success.
Is there something like remove_member_object_pointer somewhere hidden in the standard? Which is what I would need but can't seem to find..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Member pointers and regular pointers are completely different types. There is nothing you can add or remove to go from a member pointer to a regular object pointer. You need a dedicated type trait.

```
// General case
// If a type isn't supported by a partial specialization
//  it will use this case and fail to compile
template<class T>
struct mbrptr_to_type;

// Partial specialization that matches any data member pointer type
// T C::* means "pointer to member of type `T` in class `C`"
template<class T, class C>
struct mbrptr_to_type<T C::*> {
    // Save the member type so it can be retrieved
    using type = T;
};

// Helper alias
template<class T>
using mbrptr_to_type_t = typename mbrptr_to_type<T>::type;
```

Using your test case :

```
struct DataObj
{
    char member[32];
};

// myType will be char[32]
using myType = mbrptr_to_type_t<decltype(&DataObj::member)>;

// Verification
#include <type_traits>
static_assert(std::is_same<char[32], myType>::value);
```

Live example : [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/aX-VB_)

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I needed! I've never thought about using templates this way and the ::* syntax was also new to me. Do you, by any chance, know a good ressource on where to learn about this kind of type traits template programming? Thanks again

Comment: @robo This use of templates is called partial template specialization. You can read about it [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization). The syntax here is how you declare a [pointer to data member](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_data_members). There's basically 4 kinds of pointers. Regular object pointers (the usual `int*` kind), data member pointers (like you see here), [pointers to functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_functions) and pointers to member functions (which combines the last two).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about references, you can do the following in-place:

```
using member_t = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(std::declval<DataObj>().member)>;
```

It is less general but a bit shorter then the other answer.

Comment: I hadn't thought of using `declval` to get the member directly. But this approach doesn't work if you only have a member pointer type like `memberObjPtr`. So, depending on what OP is actually trying to solve, this answer may be better than mine or it may not applicable.

Comment: I interpreted the question like OP has more than a member pointer. But I think your answer is much more elegant and general. Mine is more the quick and dirty, if you only have to do that once.